# I want to stop line of code being read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program that generates prime numbers (yes i am still pretty new to python). My issue is that I want to have an option to keep track of how many calculations are made during the process(using 'yncalc' variable), but if i use an if statement(around the 'calculations += 1' line) the time calculating time goes up a lot. Is there anyway I could block out a line of code being read through a command or something without extra calculating time?

Here is my code

```
import time

howMany = input("How many prime numbers to solve?\n")
yncalc = input("Keep track of calculations?(slower)\nY or N:")

text = open('PrimeNumbers.txt', 'w')
t = time.clock()
t2 = time.time()
number = 2
primes = []
x1 = 2
x2 = 2
calculations = 0
while True:
    if x1 * x2 == number:
        number += 1
        x1 = 2
        x2 = 2
    elif x1 < (number / x2):
        x1 += 1
    elif x1 >= (number / x2) and x2 < number:
        x1 = 2
        x2 += 1
    else:
        if (time.clock() - t) > 2:
            t = time.clock()
            print(primes[-1])
            print(len(primes))
        if len(primes) == int(howMany):
            break
        primes.append(number)
        number += 1
        x1 = 2
        x2 = 2

   calculations += 1

text.write('%s prime numbers\n' % (len(primes)))
text.write(str(primes))
text.write('\nFinished in %s seconds and took %s calculations' % (str(time.time() - t2)[0:3], calculations))
```

Comment: You could just keep the code as-is and always display the number of calculations at the end, since incrementing an integer is less expensive than the `if` statement. How much slower is the code if you remove the `calculations` variable, anyway?

Comment: BTW, You don't need `x1 >= (number / x2)` in the second `elif`. That's guaranteed to be true because you already tested the opposite in the previous `elif`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to tell Python to ignore a particular statement.

Comment: @AdilB it adds alot at higher number, its around 30% i think.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks :) That speed it up alot

Comment: If yuo really want to speed things up, implement Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @Barmar ill do that in school tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, I'm confused as to why not simply use an if statement. I ran the numbers for 2000 samples. On my machine it only costs 1-second.

```
calc = yncalc in ("y", "Y", "yes", "Yes")

while True: 

    # your code

    if calc: 
        calculations += 1
```

My Results: 2000 samples

- False: 52 seconds   (answered 'n')
- True: 68 seconds    (answered 'y')
- No if statement: 67 seconds   (left calculation +=1 with no if)
- No calculations statement: 51 seconds (took out statement entirely)

Comment: on my computer doing 2000 primes i get a 28% difference between nothing and if statement no.                                                                                 nothing: 83 seconds
just calculations:101
if statement (No):115
if statement (Yes):131

Comment: I don&#39;t have a good answer for that, I&#39;m afraid. Are you certain you pre calculate the yncal to bool?

Comment: I had no idea that you could even do that or use the "in" operator that way (like i said i'm still quite new to python). i ran the same thing again and its 6 seconds slower (88 seconds total), which is way better. Thanks for the help.